# Error accessing Azure AD Graph explorer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to access the Azure AD Graph Explorer using my administrator account. When I try to access it, it shows this error:

> Selected user account does not exist in tenant `graphExplorerMT` and cannot access the application `d3ce4cf8-6810-442d-b42e-375e14710095` in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.

What shall I do?

Comment: Is the account you're using the subscription administrator, or an administrator in the Azure AD tenant you are trying to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try with a user that is internal to the AAD or add your MS account as an external user to it.
The Azure subscription admin is not necessarily part of the Azure Active Directory.

Comment: how to add my MS account as an external user?

Comment: Create a new user under AAD as global admin. Also, I guess this documentation reference link will help you understand to manage various AAD users https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn919674.aspx

Comment: You cannot use MS Account to login AAD Graph Explorer.:-)

Answer (score 0):

For Azure AD Graph Explorer, you can only use the member account(internal) to sign in, such as `xxx.onmicrosoft.com`.

You cannot use a guest user account(external) to sign in AAD Graph Explorer.

**Solutions:**

Try to sign in AAD Graph Explorer with a member account.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ace1bcf4-4dff-4131-abf9-b21385bc13f5/azure-ad-graph-explorer?forum=WindowsAzureAD) on Microsoft's forum, this does not work with Microsoft accounts.

> Are you trying to sign in using a Microsoft account (outlook/live)  into https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/ ?
>
> Azure AD Graph explorer cannot authenticate social accounts and only works with work or school accounts in Azure AD.
>
> You would have to use the latest MS graph, if you want to use MSA accounts